# Is there a way to test / assert output from Write-Host using Pester?

Tags: powershell, pester

I'm writing tests for a fairly complex script and there's one particular function in the script that will output different series of logging messages to the user.  I would like to assert whether a particular logging message is being displayed.

The main issue is that I don't know what parameter is implicitly handling the text that I'm passing the `Write-Host` cmdlet.

Here is some code that captures the premise of what I am trying to do...

### Function to test

```
function TestFunction($TestInput) {
    if ($TestInput -contains 1) {
        Write-Host "TestInput contains a 1"
    }

    if ($TestInput -contains 3 ) {
        Write-Host "TestInput contains a 3"
    }

    if ($TestInput -contains 4 ) {
        Write-Host "TestInput contains a 4"
    }
}
```

### Pester test

```
Describe "TestFunction" {
    It "should call Write-Host with appropriate message if 1 or 3 is passed" {
        Mock Write-Host {}
        TestFunction -TestInput @(1, 2, 3)
        Assert-MockCalled Write-Host -Exactly 2 -Scope It
        Assert-MockCalled Write-Host -Exactly 1 -Scope It -ParameterFilter { "TestInput contains a 1" }
        Assert-MockCalled Write-Host -Exactly 1 -Scope It -ParameterFilter { "TestInput contains a 3" }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
  Describing TestFunction
    [-] should call Write-Host with appropriate message if 1 or 3 is passed 19ms
      at <ScriptBlock>, : line 235
      235:         Assert-MockCalled Write-Host -Exactly 1 -Scope It -ParameterFilter { "TestInput contains a 1" }
      Expected Write-Host to be called 1 times exactly but was called 2 times
Tests completed in 106ms
Tests Passed: 0, Failed: 1, Skipped: 0, Pending: 0, Inconclusive: 0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reviewing the [Microsoft documentation for the `Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7) cmdlet, I found that there is an `-Object` parameter.  This accepts an array of generic objects to write to the console.  The `-Object` parameter is the parameter which needs to be specified in the `-ParameterFilter` of the Pester tests in order to assert that the appropriate text is being displayed.

My updated code is as follows...

### Function to test

```
function TestFunction($TestInput) {
    if ($TestInput -contains 1) {
        Write-Host "TestInput contains a 1"
    }

    if ($TestInput -contains 3 ) {
        Write-Host "TestInput contains a 3"
    }

    if ($TestInput -contains 4 ) {
        Write-Host "TestInput contains a 4"
    }
}
```

### Pester test

```
Describe "TestFunction" {
    It "should call Write-Host with appropriate message if 1 or 3 is passed" {
        Mock Write-Host {}
        TestFunction -TestInput @(1, 2, 3)
        Assert-MockCalled Write-Host -Exactly 2 -Scope It
        Assert-MockCalled Write-Host -Exactly 1 -Scope It -ParameterFilter { $Object -eq "TestInput contains a 1" }
        Assert-MockCalled Write-Host -Exactly 1 -Scope It -ParameterFilter { $Object -eq "TestInput contains a 3" }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
  Describing TestFunction
    [+] should call Write-Host with appropriate message if 1 or 3 is passed 20ms
Tests completed in 99ms
Tests Passed: 1, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Pending: 0, Inconclusive: 0
```

Comment: `-Times 2 -Exactly`, also for some strange reason `-Scope It` only worked correctly for me when `It` was case sensitive, otherwise `it` was counting results from other it blocks as well

Comment: If you are mocking a function that is called from within a module, you need to include the `-ModuleName` when defining the mock. e.g. `Mock -ModuleName YourModule Write-Host {}`. Mocking Docs: https://pester.dev/docs/usage/mocking, Module Mocking Docs: https://pester.dev/docs/usage/modules